# Vs code autocomplete not recognizing tsconfig paths for node_modules with custom export rules

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, pnpm

I am working in a pnpm workspace setup. The folder structure looks like the following

```
PNPM-WORKSPACE
lib/package.json
lib/generated/a.js
app/tsconfig.json
app/src/b.js
```

The package.json in the library I am importing modifies the export path of the folder to remove the generated folder name where the generated code is present.

```
  "exports": {
    "./*": "./generated/*.js"
  },
```

So import of `a.js` which should have been `lib/generated/a` becomes `lib/a`.

To make Typescript and VS code understand, I have added a path in the `tsconfig.json` under `app`.

```
paths: {
 "lib/*": ["node_modules/lib/generated/*]
}
```

This works, but the autocomplete in VS code doesn't work. It still recommends `lib/generated/a`. This path is wrong now. Any ideas how to support it? I have looked at a lot of articles, didn't find a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's your VS Code setting `typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier` set to? does your project have a tsconfig.json or jsconfig.json file?

Comment: I have tried all the options in `typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier`. yes, it has a tsconfig.json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer to this problem. The way is to use the `typesVersions` in the package.json. So, we would need a new entry in our lib package.json file.

```
  "typesVersions": {
    "*": {
      "*": ["./generated/*"]
    }
  },
```

This solved it for me.